# What is the expression for current density of a ring in spherical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current, dimensional-analysis

I am not understanding the following expression for the current density of  a ring of radius $a$ : $$J_{\phi}= I \sin\theta'\delta (\cos\theta')\delta(r'-a)/a.$$ It is dimensionally correct. I do not know how the normalization was done to get the total current.  This is Jackson 5.33 of Section 5.5. I am sorry to ask a homework-like question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ring of current $I$ is at the parallel $r=r_0$ and $\theta=\theta_0$, then:
$$
j = I\delta(\theta-\theta_0)\frac{\delta(r-r_0)}{r_0}e_\phi
$$
This is dimensionally correct, like your expression. Indeed, when looking at the current flowing through a half plane $\phi=cst$, using:
$$
\int_0^\pi d\theta\int_0^\infty dr r \delta(\theta-\theta_0)\frac{\delta(r-r_0)}{r_0} = 1
$$
you do get a total current $I$. You need to use the 2D area element (same as polar coordinates):
$$
d\theta rdr
$$

In general, if it is not located at a singular point of the coordinate system, you just need to divide by the 2D Jacobean at that point.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my expression, J has the dimension of Ampere/m^2. So it is current per unit area. Your solution has the dimensions of current per unit volume. I do not know how Jackeson arrived at the expression.

Comment: Right, my bad, corrected the mistakes. I mixed up the volume element and the surface element.

Comment: THis is explained in the following thread.https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128732/describing-a-circular-current-loop-as-delta-functions?rq=1